# Write File and Save it as a .htm

Tags: c#

I Write the text file Demo.txt with Html tags i have save it as html(every time when i write it again)
this is my code...

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"D:\Demo.txt", string.Empty);
        StreamWriter file2 = new StreamWriter(@"D:\Demo.txt", true);
        int j = 0;
        file2.WriteLine("<html><table  border='1'>");
        file2.WriteLine("<tr bgcolor='#99CCFF' >");
        file2.WriteLine("</html>");
```

how to save it as .htm alredy having extention .txt...how to refresh text file or save it with .htm

Comment: Can you not use extension .htm when opening `StreamWriter`? like `System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"D:\Demo.htm", string.Empty);StreamWriter file2 = new StreamWriter(@"D:\Demo.htm", true);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conditionally copy the file before or after you write to it.

```
if(System.IO.File.Exists("d:\Demo.txt"))    
    System.IO.File.Copy("d:\Demo.txt", "d:\Demo.htm", true);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.copy.aspx